# change default options of a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I used a plugin that have a method `tagsInput` like this :

```
$.fn.tagsInput = function(options) {
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
      interactive:true,
      defaultText:'add a tag',
      minChars:0,
      width:'300px',
      height:'100px',
      autocomplete: {selectFirst: false },
      hide:true,
      delimiter: ',',
      unique:true,
      removeWithBackspace:true,
      placeholderColor:'#666666',
      autosize: true,
      comfortZone: 20,
      inputPadding: 6*2
    },options);
```

Now I want to change `defaultText` option of that in my scripts where act for all plugin instances.

I readed [this article](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/), but could not solve it .

Comment: `$(elem).tagsInput({ defaultText : 'something else' })`

Comment: this is only for specific elements. I want to set default for all instances.

Comment: Then you'd have to change the plugin and hardcode the value